# Error 340 | How do I install all the modules required for svg-to-json.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

I'm trying to use an SVG-to-JSON converter (https://github.com/chrisfinch/svg-to-json) so that I can turn vector images into paths using JSON and then i plan to use d3.js to visualise the data.

Once I've got all the modules I need in the right place, it seems I just type:

```
node svg-to-json.js myFile.txt
```

(where the txt file is the text version of an svg file) and hey presto, i'll have a nice JSON output.

To do this, it seems I need to use the terminal app (I'm on a mac running Yosemite), which is fairly new to me.

I've downloaded the open sourced files (link above).

I've installed npm and jsdom (version 3, so it will work with node) via command line. But every time I try to run the conversion command, I'm told one or other module is missing. Each time, I install another module. So far I've installed parse5, cssom, htmlparser2, cssstyle, nwmatcher, xml-name-validator, contextify and bindings modules.

I wonder how many there are and whether there is a quicker way.

But for now anyway I'm stuck. I've installed the bindings module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bindings

But my terminal app throws an error, not finding it. I've put it in the same location as all the other modules but this doesn't work.

This was the error:

```
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:  → /Users/Em/Documents/dataviz_maps/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/contextify/build/contextify.node  → /Users/Em/Documents/dataviz_maps/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/contextify/build/Debug/contextify.node → /Users/Em/Documents/dataviz_maps/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/contextify/build/Release/contextify.node → /Users/Em/Documents/dataviz_maps/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/contextify/out/Debug/contextify.node → /Users/Em/Documents/dataviz_maps/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/contextify/Debug/contextify.node  → /Users/Em/Documents/dataviz_maps/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/contextify/out/Release/contextify.node → /Users/Em/Documents/dataviz_maps/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/contextify/Release/contextify.node → /Users/Em/Documents/dataviz_maps/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/contextify/build/default/contextify.node → /Users/Em/Documents/dataviz_maps/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/contextify/compiled/0.10.31/darwin/x64/contextify.node
    at bindings (/Users/Em/Documents/dataviz_maps/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/bindings.js:88:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Em/Documents/dataviz_maps/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:1:96)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Em/Documents/dataviz_maps/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:5:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

I tried dragging the bindings folder within the contextify folder as the error details suggest that that is where it's looking. But no luck.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Emma

Comment: Did you install the modules by running `npm install` next to the svg-to-json project's `package.json`?

Comment: my terminal directory is set to svg-to-json-master, which is a folder holding a package.json, and a node_modules folder, which contains all the modules (most of which have their own package.json). I ran the initial npm install from the svg-to-json-master folder, before i installed any modules. Now npm install fails, citing contextify as the problem.

Comment: It might be a mac problem with the contextify library. I ran `git clone https://github.com/chrisfinch/svg-to-json.git; cd svg-to-json; npm install` and contextify built alright. When I try and run the script I get "jsdom 4.x onward only works on io.js, not Node.js" so fix that by changing jsdom version to `3.x` in package.json, and it works for me (on windows) \o/

Comment: You could try `npm cache clean; npm install` but if that is still having problems you should probably proceed to search and open contextify issues