# svg-to-json.js | where has my file gone?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, svg, npm

I think I've finally installed all the bits I need for svg-to-json.js to work (see previous post: [Error 340 | How do I install all the modules required for svg-to-json.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165559/error-340-how-do-i-install-all-the-modules-required-for-svg-to-json-js)). Github location: https://github.com/chrisfinch/svg-to-json

Now I run the command:

> node svg-to-json.js filename.txt

and it's meant to generate a .json file. But where is that file? And will it be called filename.json?

My command looks like it's worked in terminal, where it says:

> Emmas-MacBook-Air:svg-to-json-master Em$ node svg-to-json.js men.txt
>
> 1 files detected...
>
> Reading file:  file1.txt
>
> Parsing a DOM for:  file1

file1.txt is in my svg-to-json-master folder, where the terminal is running the code. But there is no sign of a json file.

I am new to using the command line prompt so maybe i'm doing something silly...

Any tips appreciated
Emma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using node.js you will have to change the package.json file to use jsdom v3.x, otherwise it will produce the error:

```
/Users/guest/test/svg-to-json-master/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js:3
`jsdom 4.x onward only works on io.js, not Node.js™: https://github.com/tmpvar
```

I changed the desired version in package.json and ran npm install again.

```
"dependencies" : {
  "buffered-reader":  "*",
  "jsdom" :  "3.x",
  "eval" :  "*",
  "raphael-browserify"  : "*"
```

After running the script again I got the proper result:

```
svg-to-json-master$ node svg-to-json.js test.svg

1 files detected...

Reading file:  test.svg

Parsing a DOM for:  test.svg

Layers OK; attempting to write file...

test.svg_svg-to-json.json was saved!
```

Comment: thanks for this. I had already installed the older version of jsdom. Sadly for me it isn't that :o(

Comment: Could it be the data? I tested with the sample SVG from the Github readme

Comment: OMG you're a genius! Thanks! I have no idea why my svg/txt files weren't working but the sample SVG did work. Thanks!!